# Using Lpad and column headings

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, truncate

Here's my query:

```
SQL> select first_name, lpad(first_name, 5, ' ') as padded_value
  2  from employees
  3  where first_name like 'M%';
```

and the output:

```
FIRST_NAME           PADDE                                                      
-------------------- -----                                                      
Mozhe                Mozhe                                                      
Michael              Micha                                                      
Mattea               Matte                                                      
Michael              Micha                                                      
Martha               Marth                                                      
Matthew              Matth                                                      

6 rows selected.
```

The second argument being set (`5`) makes the ouput give correct number of characters from the character string but also truncates the column heading alias...and the default column header (I tried both ways).

Why is that?  How do I write the query to truncate the data returned and NOT the column headings?

Comment: This is how SQLPlus works if I'm not mistaken. I don't think you can change this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL*Plus command `col padded_value format a12`.

See the [SQL*Plus docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve013.htm#SQPUG034).

Comment: Thanks..that was simple enough.  I researched the docs...I guess I missed it.